# StreamingHttpResponse not working with ASGI but work fine with WSGI

Tags: django, django-views, django-channels, django-wsgi

I'm trying to use `channels` for some WebSockets-related stuff, but it keeps loading and not showing any streaming response when I reload my web page. Here is my code which works fine with this setting:

```py
# settings.py
# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application' # work fine
ASGI_APPLICATION = "main.asgi.application"  # not working
```

And here is my `views.py`:

```py
@gzip.gzip_page  # for performance
def video_stream(request: HttpRequest):
    video = VideoContainer.objects.last()
    video_path = video.file.path
    return StreamingHttpResponse(generate_frames(VideoCamera(video_path)),
                                 content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
```

Here is my code for `generate_frames` and `VideoCamera`:

```py
import cv2


class VideoCamera:
    def __init__(self, video_path: str):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        while (self.video.isOpened()):
            img = self.video.read()[1]

            # because web-page looking for image/jpeg content type
            jpeg = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1]
            return jpeg.tobytes()  # we stream it in byte form for frontend


def generate_frames(camera) -> bytes:
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Comment: Hi did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but a few days ago I notice that it works but in a different way. First, it loads all stream and then starts playing with 2x speed.

Comment: Hi @Mubashar anything unique that you did?

Answer (score 0):

I was going through a similar problem. I ended up running both WSGI and ASGI for my application on different ports. Gunicorn ran on port 8000 using WSGI for all http requests using StreamingHttpResponse and Daphne ran on port 8001 using ASGI for all channel related stuff.

```
gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --daemon
daphne -p 8001 my_project.asgi:application
```